# How to resize the selected image?

Tags: iphone, blackberry

I want to set the image in my profile of my application.
But it is not fix in the PictureField.
I want to resize that image and display it in PictureField.
please give me the direction to do this.

Comment: Which is it, iPhone or Blackberry? And in either case, this is a pretty poor question. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i am developing application for both iphone and blackberry .

Comment: In that case, the solution is unlikely to be the same for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For blackberry the following code will helpful to you.

```
Bitmap temp = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("Image.png");
Bitmap scale = new Bitmap(width, Height);
temp.scaleInto(scale, Bitmap.FILTER_BILINEAR);
```